# When is it proper to use unique key in a table than a primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Since primary key and unique is similar. I have trouble grasping the concept of the two. I know primary key doesnt accept null and unique key accepts a null once. Since a null value is a unique value so it can be only accepted once. But the idea of primary key is having a uniqueness in every row. which a unique key also do. thats why im asking when is it proper to use primary key over unique key and vice versa.

Comment: "unique key accepts a null once": That's not true. Plus, I think you should read some resources online, it's not going to be easy to summarize the concepts in one StackOverflow post.

Comment: i asked this question because i have trouble finding scenario in my head where i would use a unique key.maybe i have an empty brain thats why i cant find one!haha

Comment: A username would be a good example. You might want usernames to be unique but using a generated ID number as the PK would make it much easier to allow people to change their username as you wouldn't have to change your other tables. You could also change the username size easier as well.

Comment: You may also want to learn about the concepts of candidate keys and super keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A UNIQUE constraint is similar to PRIMARY key, but you can have more than one UNIQUE constraint per table.

When you declare a UNIQUE constraint, SQL Server creates a UNIQUE index to speed up the process of searching for duplicates. In this case the index defaults to NONCLUSTERED index, because you can have only one CLUSTERED index per table.

- The number of UNIQUE constraints per table is limited by the number of indexes on the table i.e 249 NONCLUSTERED index and one possible CLUSTERED index.

Contrary to PRIMARY key UNIQUE constraints can accept NULL but just once. If the constraint is defined in a combination of fields, then every field can accept NULL and can have some values on them, as long as the combination values is unique.

Also Refer other link ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx))

Comment: UNIQUE constraints allow for the value NULL. However, as with any value participating in a UNIQUE constraint, only one null value is allowed per column. 
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx)

Comment: That's bizarre and rather unexpected given that `null = x` is never true for any `x` (or does SQL Server violate that too?). Thanks for the supporting documentation though.

Comment: @muistooshort: yes, SQL Server has famously got it wrong. In standard SQL a UNIQUE constraint is not violated by multiple nulls. Note the misstatement, "only one null value" (hint: null is not a value, the SQL standard refers to "**the** null value"), which is probably telling.

Answer (score 5):

Executive summary: It is important for every base table to have a key, using either `PRIMARY KEY` or `NOT NULL UNIQUE`. The difference between the two is not a relational consideration and is not important from a logical point of view; rather, it is merely a psychological consideration.

---

> a relvar can have several keys, but we choose just one for underlining
>   and call that one the primary key.  The choice is arbitrary, so the
>   concept of primary is not really very important from a logical point
>   of view.  The general concept of key, however, is very important!  The
>   term candidate key means exactly the same as key (i.e., the addition
>   of candidate has no real significance—it was proposed by Ted Codd
>   because he regarded each key as a candidate for being nominated as the
>   primary key)... SQL allows a subset of a table's columns to be
>   declared as a key for that table.  It also allows one of them to be
>   nominated as the primary key.  Specifying a key to be primary makes
>   for a certain amount of convenience in connection with other
>   constraints that might be needed

[What Is a Key? by Hugh Darwen](http://web.onetel.com/~hughdarwen/M359/What-Is-a-Key.html)

---

> it's usual... to single out one key as the primary key (and any other
>   keys for the relvar in question are then said to be alternate keys).
>   But whether some key is to be chosen as primary, and if so which one,
>   are essentially psychological issues, beyond the purview of the
>   relational model as such. As a matter of good practice, most base
>   relvars probably should have a primary key—but, to repeat, this rule,
>   if it is a rule, really isn't a relational issue as such... Strong
>   recommendation [to SQL users]: For base tables, at any rate, use
>   PRIMARY KEY and/or UNIQUE specifications to ensure that every such
>   table does have at least one key.

[SQL and Relational Theory: How to Write Accurate SQL Code](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WuZGD5tBfMwC&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=%22to+single+out+one+key+as+the+primary+key%22&source=bl&ots=WepV_mJFIz&sig=H6g6r1385UiRnP-igDKVIfpJqp4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-hxXT8DDOaGM4gS90oTiDw&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22to%20single%20out%20one%20key%20as%20the%20primary%20key%22&f=false)
By C. J. Date

---

In standard SQL `PRIMARY KEY`

- implies uniqueness but you can specify that explicitly (using `UNIQUE`).
- implies `NOT NULL` but you can specify that explicitly when creating columns (but you should be avoiding nulls anyhow!)
- allows you to omit its columns in a `FOREIGN KEY` but you can specify them explicitly.
- can be declared for only one key per table but it is not clear why (Codd, who originally proposed the concept, did not impose such a restriction).

In some products `PRIMARY KEY` implies the table's clustered index but you can specify that explicitly (you may not want the primary key to be the clustered index!)

For some people  `PRIMARY KEY` has purely psychological significance:

- they think it signifies that the key will be referenced in a foreign key (this was proposed by Codd but not actually adopted by standard SQL nor SQL vendors).
- they think it signifies the sole key of the table (but the failure to enforce other candidate keys leads to loss of data integrity).
- they think it implies a 'surrogate' or 'artificial ' key with no significance to the business (but actually imposes unwanted significance on the enterprise by being exposed to users).

Answer (score 0):

A table can have multiple UNIQUE key  but only one PRIMARY key is allowed for a table.
IF your unique key is a NOT NUL UNIQUE KEY then it is always a good idea to promote it to PRIMARY KEY.
If your storage engine is INNODB and if you don't have any PRIMARY key then innodb automatically creates a internal HEXDECIMAL PRIMARY key which will have some performance impact, hence it is better to create a primary key always with INNODB storage engine.

Comment: "F your unique key is a NOT NUL UNIQUE KEY then it is always a good idea to promote it to PRIMARY KEY" -- You make a convincing case for INNODB but why do you say **always**?

Answer (score 0):

A PK is considered to be an unique identifier of the row. It should never be subject to changes. For example the ID of the User.

An UK is considered to be unique throughout the whole column. It is not necessarily an identifier of the row as it may be subject to changes. For example the username or email address of the User.